# Finding RedHat applications

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm new to RedHat, and confused and frustrated. I want to run the application called "Nautilus". According to the "Add/Remove Software" utility, Nautilus is already installed on my system, but I cannot find it.

Where is Nautilus on my system? I've tried using the "Search for files..." utility in vain. There is no shortcut for it in the "Applications" drop-down menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus is the default file manager installed for RedHat's GUI.  You dont need to run it manually.  All you need to do is open the file system by double clicking the "computer" icon, or the "Home Directory" icon, or on any mounted drive or folder.

Comment: How do I enter the directory path manually (such as `smb://workspace`)?